# Fragment not Generated in AppSync Sample App

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, aws-appsync

I'm going through the sample app for AppSync as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/quickstart-launch-a-sample-schema.html).

I found a sample Android client app on GitHub [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-appsync-events-starter-android) and am trying to just get it to run with my data but for some reason the fragments aren't being generated.

[image]

events.graphql has what appears to be the events fragment definition.

```
fragment Event on Event {
  id
  description
  name
  when
  where
  comments {
    items {
      eventId
      commentId
      content
      createdAt
    }
  }
```

I've tried adding it to the schema in the appsync web interface and it saves the schema but then doesn't actually add the fragment.  I'm just now trying GraphQL tonight so I'm not really sure where to even put the fragment definition and Google doesn't seem to have anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

Going to need more information here before answering, but I'm working on the same sample project and was able to get it working so I might be of some help.

Is your project syncing and building? That's a good first step.
It looks like your .graphql files are being autogenerated in your app-> source -> appsync -> com file, but the classes are not being generated in the app -> *build* -> source -> appsync -> com folder.

Something I learned in the process of working on this project was that it's important to have all your resolvers and the backend set up fairly completely in the AWS console before calling the `amplify add api` command. Have you setup the back end with resolvers?

If you have and it's still not working, try running in the app terminal `amplify gql-compile` then running `amplify push`to pull the data back into your app from the console, then resync and rebuild as necessary. This should build your Query/Mutation/Subscription classes for you, as well as the Fragment.class, which are the resolvers in your program for the .graphql queries/etc that you want to run in your application.

If that doesn't work, make sure you've completed all the necessary steps in the amplify API like `amplify add api`, `amplify update api`. It appears that you've already done that since you have generated .graphql files in the app-> source directory, but in case you haven't, those are first steps. You can also check to make sure that you're actually connected to the DB (and correct api in the console) by running `amplify status`. Are you connected to the console API that you need to be connected to?

As a last resort, you can copy the Event.class file from github and paste it into the appropriate file/subdirectory, along with the rest of the Query/Mutation/etc .class files that should have been generated by the ApolloGraphql plugin.